# populate a 'select list' from a directory on my server using php and html

Tags: php, html

Is it possible (I am assuming not) to populate a drop down list from files that are on my website, say in the images folder? in a html form?

```
<select name="s1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
  <?php 
       foreach(glob('/images/*') as $filename){
       $rest = substr($filename, 7);    
       echo "<li><a href='#'>".$rest."</a></li>";
    }
?>

</select>
```

Comment: You probably want to use `<option>` instead of `<li>` in your `foreach`. What goes wrong with your code?

Comment: It just doesnt read any files in the directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<select name="s1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
  <?php 
       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/*') as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
```

Comment: Way later here, but having the same problem. I incorporated this code (substituting `/images/*` for `../Data/*` and no files show up in the drop-down. This is part of a d3 viz in the browser. Any idea what I could be missing off the top of your head?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `scandir` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Then just run a `foreach` on the returned array and echo `<option>` for each one.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `scandir`.

Comment: I dont know how to do this sorry but I will look into it. Thanks