# Populating Dropdown with filenames from a directory In PHP

Tags: php

I was trying to populate my dropdown menu with file names from a directory, I have searched for articles here at SO regarding this inquiry I found several answers and tried them but none of them seems to work which I find weird because they were chosen as answers and some of them have High votes
take this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177524/populate-a-select-list-from-a-directory-on-my-server-using-php-and-html) for example this is one of the reference that I have tried but it seems like it does not work for me

Here is my code based on the reference link that I Have provided

```
<select name="templ" class="form-control input-sm">
    <?php 
         foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/els-content/*') as $filename){
             $filename = basename($filename);
             echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename. </option>";
         }
    ?>  
</select>
```

this does not return any values at all. What could be the problem ?

Comment: The problem could be that "dirname(__FILE__) . '/els-content/*'" doesn't exist.

Comment: hmm thats weird I'm pretty sure that the directory is there but since you've pointed that out I'm going to double check it

Comment: @bobdye your right `dirname(FILE) . '/els-content/*` doesnt exist because it looking at the current directory I'll post my answer for everyone's reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Ok so I was able to answer my own question because of what @bobdye had pointed out, okayyy I'll cut to the chase here is how it was solved

```
dirname(FILE) . '/els-content/*'
```

returns the current directory plus the string `'/els-content/*'` which my problem is the files from els-content does not show on my dropdown so I used `echo` to check what does that return so I find out that it returns something like this

```
Users/WhosPC/Desktop/cms_form/myPadmin/els-content/*
```

in which `els-content` is FOUND OUTSIDE the `myPadmin` meaning `els-content` is on the same level as my `myPadmin` so what I did was I used `chdir()` then used `getcwd()` inside a variable

so what it look like was

```
                   <?php
                        chdir('../');
                      $s =  getcwd();
                        ?>
                    <select name="templ" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <?php 
                           foreach(glob($s . '/els-content/*') as $filename){
                           $filename = basename($filename);
                           echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";

                        }
                    ?>  
                        </select>
```

although I'm not sure if `chdir('../')` and `getcwd()` is reliable enough for this kind of task.. when this cms baby is on the real world up and runnning

feel free to critize this script so I can improve this further

UPDATED CODE

```
             $s =  realpath(getcwd()."/..");
                    foreach(glob($s . '/els-content/*') as $filename){
                   $filename = basename($filename);

                   echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>". $filename."</option>";

                }
```

Ok I didnt delete the 1st version of my code so that users who stumble on this post could see the difference of the 1st one and the 2nd code that 
@prodigitalson had pointed out on my 1st code snippet

Comment: I would just use `$s = realpath(__DIR__ .'/../els-content');` or `dirname(__FILE__)` in place of the `__DIR__` constant. Though you would want to check that `realpath` successfully returned a value.

Comment: Hi @prodigitalson  tried your suggestion but seems like its not working check my code 
`$s =  realpath(__DIR__ .'/../els-content/');
            foreach(glob($s . 'single-*.{php,html}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename){
            $filename = basename($filename);
            $bs = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.'));
            $bs = substr($bs,-5);
            echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".ucfirst($bs)."</option>";

         }`

Comment: Well the value of `__DIR__` will depend on the file its used in. So if for example you are several levels down the include chain then the path may not be what you think it. Whereas `getcwd` is base on the working directory of the actual script being run.

Comment: You could use `realpath(getcwd() .'/../els-content/')` i would jsut shy away from using chdir in this context.

Comment: no good still it returns none `foreach(glob(realpath(getcwd() . '/els-content/*')) as $filename){
            $filename = basename($filename);
            $bs = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.'));
            $parts = explode("-", $bs);
          $bsh = $parts[1];
            echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".ucfirst($bsh)."</option>";`
Tried to echo as string and none showed at all

Comment: btw @prodigitalson are there any casulaties on using `chdir()`?

Comment: `glob(realpath(getcwd() . '/els-content/*')` you forgot your `../` - should be `glob(realpath(getcwd() . '/../els-content/*')`. And yes in some cases you might get includes thrown off if you dont `chdir` back to the original `cwd`. Generally speaking that should be an edge case, but I would just avoid it all together.

Comment: hi @prodigitalson For some reason the code became like this
 `$s =  realpath(getcwd()."/.."); foreach(glob($s . '/els-content/*') as $filename){}`  although I'm not sure if this is fine since your suggested snippet `glob(realpath(getcwd() . '/../els-content/*')` did not work at all to my side anyway I have updated my answer based on your tips