# Dynamically Fill Drop-down from Directory so User Selects d3.js JSON Data

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, d3.js

I have a d3 forced-directed graph powered by a static JSON file:

```
d3.json("../Data/sample.json", function(error, graph) {
     //do stuff
});
```

Instead of calling a specific JSON file, I would like the user to select which file to use from a drop-down in the browser that is populated by all the files in a specific folder (the "Data" folder which is one level back).

My attempt at creating the drop-down with PHP based on this question ([populate a 'select list' from a directory on my server using php and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177524/populate-a-select-list-from-a-directory-on-my-server-using-php-and-html)):

```
<select name="s1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select File</option>
  <?php 
       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '../Data/*') as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
```

This code is after the `</head>` tag in my html, but before the `<script>` tags. This results in a drop-down where the only option is "Select File", with none of the JSON files in the "Data" folder represented. How do I get the files to show up in the drop-down? Then, how do I drive the d3 visualization with the selected file? I imagine there is some type of `on-event` that could be used, but I'm not sure where to begin.

I'm now realizing that php cannot inherently be included in a `.html` file and work properly. What is the best way to either include it or use pure html/javascript to create the drop-down? Eventually the viz will be hosted on IIS, where I assume a .htaccess file can be used. In the meantime however, development is occurring with Python's simple server.

Thank you for any insight you all might have!

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into detail how to populate the drop down menu, but I can quickly give you the code how to use a file handler, so that the user may select the JSON file which he wants to use on your D3 routine:

1) Create the input select button and register it to a file select handler function:

```
var input = d3.select("body").append("input")
        .attr("type","file")
        .on("change", handleFileSelect)
```

2) The file select handler will register a new function with the fileHandler as input on the onload callback:

```
// Single file handler
function handleFileSelect() {
    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
    } else {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    }

    var f = event.target.files[0]; // FileList object
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        load_d3(event.target.result)
    };
    // Read in the file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

3) Crete a function with a fileHandler as input, that calls your D3.json code

```
function load_d3(fileHandler) {
    d3.json(fileHandler, function(error, root) {
        //do stuff
    };
};
```

Hope this helps.